# Overriding standart close button in Unity

Tags: c#, forms, unity-game-engine, window

I want to create a "Are you sure?" system when user clicks the close button of window. Is it possible to catch FormClosing event in Unity ?
Thanks.

Edit:

```
void OnApplicationQuit()
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
        "Are you sure you want to cancel ?",
        "Question",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

I tried this to open a dialog when user clicks (X) button. It works but, looks like it creates a new dialog each frame.

Answer (score 3):

This question needs an updated answer as [Application.CancelQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CancelQuit.html) is deprecated and [MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) doesn't prevent the application from closing.

To accomplish this exit confirmation method, it's better to use: [Application.wantsToQuit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-wantsToQuit.html).

From the docs:

> Unity raises this event when the player application wants to quit.
>
> Add an event handler to this event to receive a notification that application is attempting to quit.
>
> When this event is raised the quit process has started but can be cancelled. This means the player is not guaranteed to quit. For a guaranteed quit event take a look at Application.quitting.
>
> **Return true and the quit process will continue. Return false and the quit process will cancel.**

Example:

```
// When the application starts, append a method
// that will run when the user attempts to exit
[RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
static void RunOnStart() { 
    Application.wantsToQuit += WantsToQuit;
}

public static bool quitConfirmation = false;

static bool WantsToQuit() {
    if(quitConfirmation)  {
        return true;
    } else {
         RequestQuitConfirmation();
    }
    return false;
}

static void RequestQuitConfirmation() {
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show(
        "Are you sure you want to cancel ?",
        "Question",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
        MessageBoxIcon.Question);
    if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        quitConfirmation = true;
        Application.Quit();
    }
}
```

**Note:** The return value of this event (Application.wantsToQuit) is ignored when exiting play mode in the editor. **IMPORTANT:** The return has no effect on iPhone. Application can not prevent termination under iPhone OS.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnApplicationQuit.html) and [Application.CancelQuit()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.CancelQuit.html)

Comment: Thanks. I was searching in the wrong direction for the answer. There is no need to override standart buttons. Unity already did it :)